# How to stop a timer in java

Tags: java, timer

I have a method called timer that I run everytime a user inputs something and the timer is scheduled for a minute, but I want the timer to cancel if the user enters something in less than a minute and then recall itself so the whole process happens again. My methods are below:

Input method

```
public static String run(){ 
     timer(); //runs everytime I call run()
     String s = input.nextLine();
     return s;
}
```

Timer method

```
public static void timer() {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("Times up");
        }
    };
    long delay = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1);
    Timer t = new Timer();
    t.schedule(task, delay);
}
```

method run() keeps getting called everytime someone inputs something so timer keeps getting called but that doesn't stop the previous timers though, I want the timer to stop, then recall itself so that problem doesn't exist. Anyone know a way?

Answer (score 4):

The `TimerTask` class has a method called [`cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel()) which you can call to cancel a pending timer.

In your code, you will probably need to modify your `timer()` function to return a reference to the newly created `TimerTask` object, so that you can later call `cancel()`.

Comment: so how would I make it cancel, by saying t.cancel(); ?

Comment: @user3450498 - Correct, t.cancel(); will cancel the timer. For more you can refer to java docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel()