# Stop a timer with a button

Tags: java, loops, timer

I have a start button that starts a timer with a loop.

```
public synchronized void startTourButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    new java.util.Timer().schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            try {
                byte st = presetNo[count];
                System.out.println("Start Tour Button pressed, String:  " + st);

                // this part will run from 0 to max of presets every
                // counting.
                count++;
                if (count >= MaxCount)
                    count = 0;

                byte[] command = { (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, goPreset, 0x00, st, endTx, 0x0F };
                TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

                sw.out.write(command);

            }

            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, 100, 5000);
}
```

And I have another 'Stop' Button.  Currently i am stopping the loop by breaking it and getting an Exception.  Obviously not the correct procedure and also stops the start button from working.

```
public synchronized void stopTourButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    count = -1;
}
```

My question is how do i stop it correctly so that i can restart afterwards?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop a timer in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33726952/how-to-stop-a-timer-in-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just keep a reference of the timer (a variable) and call the [`cancel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#cancel--) method.

In `startTourButtonActionPerformed`

```
//...
timer = new java.util.Timer();
timer.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() {
//...
```

In `stopTourButtonActionPerformed`

```
timer.cancel();
```

Note the it will cancel all your `timer`'s tasks. There is also a [`cancel()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html#cancel--) method on a TimerTask if you want to precisely stop only one single task.

Comment: Thanks C.Champagne. I was 99% there. 

    protected java.util.Timer timer;

was what i needed.